# cell accessory change on scrolling UITableView and textfield text also remove

Tags: iphone, objective-c

i have a table view and 4 sections in table view . in first section i have jsut one row and inside this room i added a textfield. and i assign this first cell a custom class. and for all others sections and row i assign a second class . but the problem is when i enter something in   textfield of first cell . and i `checkaccessorytype` checked for others cells and i scroll table . then textfield text finish and also cells accessory changed this is the code

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    return 4;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)table numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section

{
    if (section ==0)
    {
        return  1;
    }


    if (section ==1)
    {
        return  [filterObj.priceName count];
    }


    if (section ==2)
    {
        return  [filterObj.typeName count];
    }

    if (section ==3)
    {
        return  [othersArray count];
    }



    return 0;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *kCellID = @"DefaultCell";
     static NSString *kCellTwoID = @"tblCell";
    CustomCellWithTF *cell = (CustomCellWithTF *) [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:kCellID];
     customCellTwo *cellTwo = (customCellTwo *) [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:kCellTwoID];
    if(cell == nil)
    {
        NSArray *nibs = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"custonCell" owner:self options:nil];
        cell = (CustomCellWithTF *)[nibs objectAtIndex:0];
        cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;
        cell.textLabel.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:12];
        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellStyleDefault;

    }

    if(cellTwo == nil)
    {


        NSArray *nibsTwo = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"customCellTwo" owner:self options:nil];
        cellTwo = (customCellTwo *)[nibsTwo objectAtIndex:0];
        cellTwo.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;
        cellTwo.textLabel.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:12];
        cellTwo.accessoryType = UITableViewCellStyleDefault;
    }

    if (indexPath.section == 0 && indexPath.row == 0)
    {
        cell.textLabel.text = @"Location";
        location = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(130, 10, 150, 25)];
        [location setBorderStyle:UITextBorderStyleRoundedRect];
        location.delegate = (id)self;
        [cell addSubview:location];
        return cell;
    }

    if (indexPath.section == 1)
    {

        cellTwo.textLabel.text = [filterObj.priceName objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];


    }

    if (indexPath.section == 2)
    {
        cellTwo.textLabel.text = [filterObj.typeName objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    }

    if (indexPath.section == 3)
    {
        cellTwo.textLabel.text =[othersArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    }



    return cellTwo;






}
```

kindly tell me how i can fix this problem

Comment: You are not returning cell at all. You return cellTwo only all the time. There is lot to be changed in your code. Can you provide screenshots on what you want to achieve and what is the result?

Comment: i am returning cell you can see

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**UPDATE:**

```
    - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
    {
        static NSString *kCellID = @"DefaultCell";
         static NSString *kCellTwoID = @"tblCell";
        CustomCellWithTF *cell = (CustomCellWithTF *) [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:kCellID];
         customCellTwo *cellTwo = (customCellTwo *) [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:kCellTwoID];
        if(cell == nil)
        {
            NSArray *nibs = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"custonCell" owner:self options:nil];
            cell = (CustomCellWithTF *)[nibs objectAtIndex:0];
            cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;
            cell.textLabel.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:12];
            cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellStyleDefault;
    if (indexPath.section == 0 && indexPath.row == 0)
        {
            cell.textLabel.text = @"Location";
            location = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(130, 10, 150, 25)];
            [location setBorderStyle:UITextBorderStyleRoundedRect];
            location.delegate = (id)self;
            [cell addSubview:location];
            return cell;
        }
        }

        if(cellTwo == nil)
        {


            NSArray *nibsTwo = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"customCellTwo" owner:self options:nil];
            cellTwo = (customCellTwo *)[nibsTwo objectAtIndex:0];
            cellTwo.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;
            cellTwo.textLabel.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:12];
            cellTwo.accessoryType = UITableViewCellStyleDefault;
if (indexPath.section == 1)
        {

            cellTwo.textLabel.text = [filterObj.priceName objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];


        }

        if (indexPath.section == 2)
        {
            cellTwo.textLabel.text = [filterObj.typeName objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

        }

        if (indexPath.section == 3)
        {
            cellTwo.textLabel.text =[othersArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

        }
        }


        return cellTwo;
    }
```

Comment: but on nib file i assign identifier DefaultCell and tblCell

Comment: here you set idemtifier see  CustomCellWithTF *cell = (CustomCellWithTF *) [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:kCellID];
     customCellTwo *cellTwo = (customCellTwo *) [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:kCellTwoID];

Comment: If you do this, there is no reuse of cells(or say only when you scroll to already shown cell) which is extremely unoptimal way of implementing the UITableView, beats the very purpose.

Comment: @PraveenS but see herte when its scroll at that time its value changed bcoz its reuse the cell and with that its also set the value of current indexpath value with its array value.,..

Comment: @PraveenS now you understand what i want to say??

Comment: @ParasJoshi, bro you need to understand that indexpath is a unique identifier. Hence it generates new identifiers and scales when the number of rows/sections increases. All cells will be created but reused only when it scrolls back to them.

Comment: Your identifiers will be of tblCell01, tblCell02, tblCell11, tblCell12, tblCell21, tblCell22, tblCell23 etc. Do you get the point?

Comment: i already know bro.. i used it many time with UITableViewCell and i also solve many problem with this solution...

Comment: @ParasJoshi Ok, thats good. I hope you would have also seen memory usage increase as you scroll to the bottom, that is because your cells are not reused at all. Anyways, i rest my case here. Thanks!

Comment: @zeshan use my code just replace cellForRowAtIndexPath with my method and let me know....

Comment: @PraveenS now its correct and right for CustomeCell ?? if yes then remove ur downvote please

Comment: I know this is a waste of time, but what is cell !=nil? and cell2!=nil? Its messed up on a lot of levels.

Comment: no its still not working dude textfield text remove on scrolling i tried this technique

Comment: ohhh see here you alloc the textfield here location = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame like this when its again alloc at that time assign value with nil means "" so every time when you scroll the tableview it will blank.. i face this problem and remove with my above two optin..

Comment: i fix the textfield problem i put this code on viewdidload method .  but cell accessorytype changes on scrolling

Comment: yes dude i told you that it occure bcoz everytime its alloc .. now for accesorry here everytime check that its true or not...

Comment: oh man there is something wrong happen with this code coz cell textlabel values also changes

Comment: can you think i solved accessorytype changing problem on scrolling with assigning 4 uitableviewcell classes to 4 sections

Comment: @zeshan instead of set value here just add another chekbox in ur cell xib and set the value with its method just define method in yoyr customcell class and pass value For Ex i pass [cell setObjItem:nil title:[[arrList objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]valueForKey:@"Project_Title"] desc:[[arrList objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]valueForKey:@"Last_Date"] backImageName:strBackImageName Category:[[arrList objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]valueForKey:@"Category"]]; like you can pass value...

Comment: @zeshan yes why not... also see use the CustoCell with its class and xib... download some demo and refer that docs...

Answer (score 0):

whenever table get scrolled `cellForRowAtIndexPath:` method executes so you have to set the value globally and then set it into the textfield in `cellForRowAtIndexPath:` method and your problen will get resolved.